# Family Tree drawn like a honeycomb?

Tags: family-tree, chart-type

What I have seen in a pedigree or family tree chart is node [drawn as boxes](http://www.eprintablecalendars.com/family-tree/).

Do genealogists use hexagons to draw family tree?

I'm looking for a sample family tree drawn like a honeycomb [similar to this](https://twitter.com/familyinatree/status/615094686378659849).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is no - genealogists in general don't use hexagons to draw a family tree.

In my opinion, there's a reason why we use boxes - because it makes it clear how people are related. The hexagon chart, while quirky, is not very clear. For instance, the grandparents are not positioned directly over the parents in the normal parent-child positioning.

If you wish to include more than 2 or 3 generations, I would not advise using a honeycomb design. However, if you want a simple and attractive family tree to go above the fireplace, this design might fit the bill.